# Error en gulp tras reinstalar SO

Tags: nodejs, npm, gulp

Tuve problemas con la instalación de un programa (este no tiene nada que ver con mi pregunta) y no me quedó más remedió que formatear e instalar todo el SO y demás programas.

Tengo creada una web que utiliza gulp entre otras cosas, y tras instalar nodejs, npm y gulp fuí a modificar unas secciones de la web y al ejecutar gulp tal como siempre hago me sale un error. Bueno realmente me han ido saliendo unos cuantos pero he ido averiguando el porque de cada uno hasta este último que no sé... no uso demasiado el gulp por lo que a la hora de reinstalar todo no se si me salté algún paso por mi falta de experiencia con el programa gulp, aparte hace mucho tiempo que instalé toda la estructura base de la web.

El error es esté: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para instalar todos los paquetes de dependecías del proyecto web use el archivo package.json por lo que entiendo que este me instalo los mismos paquetes con las mismas versiones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he encontrado lo que era, pongo la respuesta por si le ocurre a alguien y le puede servir. Simplemente era por tema de versión gulp a partir de la versión 4.0 incorpora unas modificaciones incompatibles con versiones posteriores.

Mi fallo fue que instalé gulp en modo general sin especificar la versión, por lo que instalo la 4.0, al ir al proyecto y cargar el package.json instaló la versión 4.0 en el proyecto local. Cuando cambie la versión a la 3.9.1 se reparó el error.